# Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am working on ChatApp trying to save and upload images but
I get errors like this Does anyone know the cause of this ?
im getting theese type of error i cant fnd any solutons for these..

```
import 'dart:io';

//Packages
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:file_picker/file_picker.dart';

const String USER_COLLECTION = "Users";

class CloudStorageService {
  final FirebaseStorage _storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;

  CloudStorageService();

  Future<String?> saveUserImageToStorage(
      String _uid, PlatformFile _file) async {
    try {
      Reference _ref =
          _storage.ref().child('images/users/$_uid/profile.${_file.extension}');
      UploadTask _task = _ref.putFile(
        [enter image description here][1]File(_file.path),
      );
      return await _task.then(
        (_result) => _result.ref.getDownloadURL(),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  Future<String?> saveChatImageToStorage(
      String _chatID, String _userID, PlatformFile _file) async {
    try {
      Reference _ref = _storage.ref().child(
          'images/chats/$_chatID/${_userID}_${Timestamp.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.${_file.extension}');
      UploadTask _task = _ref.putFile(
        File(_file.path), ----------------> Here is the error
      );
      return await _task.then(
        (_result) => _result.ref.getDownloadURL(),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `PlatformFile.path` is a `string?`. So, you need to check if the `path` is null or not before assigning to the `File`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ! operator to convert the string to a non-nullable type

```
File(_file.path!)
```

Answer (score 0):

[The Dart programming language supports null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety). It means that in Dart nullable and non-nullable types is completely different. E.g.

```dart
bool b; // can be true or false
bool? nb; // can be true, false or null, `?` is explicit declaration, that type is nullable
```

So, `String?` and `String` is completely different types. First can be string or null, second can only be a string. And you need to check for null in your case.

Answer (score 0):

`String?` means it may have value, or it may have `null` value, but `String` means it have an appropriate value String type.
You can add `!` to the last of the data type to sure it's not `null`.

For example:

```
String? name = "Jack";
String name2 = name!;
```